# Android MarketPlace filter for 3G or 4G devices

Tags: android, filter, google-play, 3g, 4g

Can we restrict our app,so that it will be only visible/shown for 4G devices in Android Market place.

I currently have 2 apps,one for 3G and the other for 4G.I don't want the user to be 
confused by seeing 2 icons of the same app in marketplace.

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Ok,since no one updated for long time,I am updating myself.

Currently we don't have a filter for network type (like 3G/4G-LTE).

We can only restrict at application level,by checking the hardware support for 3G/4G by having conditions for HSPA,HSPA+,HSRPD,...